# DOS start command does open directory with spaces

Tags: dos

Help please..

I wanted to Open the copied file folder once the file has been copied.

I used DOS command start.  It works fine as long as the directory path does not contain any space characters.

If I use quotes in the path it rather opne another dos screen:

**Here sample CMD file:

```
XCopy C:\1\Source\Test.txt C:\1\Target 1\ /R/Y/K
start "C:\1\Target 1\"
Pause**
```

Answer (score 5):

You had the right idea with the quotes. The tricky bit is that start assumes the first parameter is the window title if it is quoted. If you want to quote your target then you *must* provide a quoted title first. It can be empty:

```
start "" "C:\1\Target 1\"
```

However, if you happen to have a batch file named `Target 1.bat`, then it will execute the batch script instead of opening the `Target 1` folder in Windows Explorer. For that reason, it is safer to use robert oh's answer, explicitly specifying `explorer` as the target with the folder as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
start explorer "c:\some folder\"
```